# Can not access EKEventStore in OSx

Tags: osx-lion, ekeventstore

I try to use EKEventStore with checking for document in web and reference. But still got below problem that seem like I can not access store in OSx. Mine is 10.7.5, please help suggest what I did wrong on this.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h" 
@implementation AppDelegate
@synthesize store = _store;
@synthesize defaultCalendar = _defaultCalendar;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    self.store = [[EKEventStore alloc] initWithAccessToEntityTypes:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    self.defaultCalendar  = [self.store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
}

- (IBAction)startPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Default calendar:%@ is nil:%@", [self.defaultCalendar title],(self.defaultCalendar));
    NSArray *calendars = [self.store calendarsForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent];
    NSLog(@"Total calendars %lu", calendars.count);
}
```

This is result that came out in Log

2013-02-02 08:24:42.429 iCalendarProfiler-Test01152013[2296:403] Default calendar:(null) is nil:(null)
2013-02-02 08:24:42.429 iCalendarProfiler-Test01152013[2296:403] Total calendars 0

Answer (score 0):

EKEventStore for OS X is available since 10.8, is not available for OS X 10.7.5